# How replace some text in a paragraph with other text in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

$string="Hello how are ##you ? I want ##join you.";

echo $string;

// now I want replace all ##.... words with <a>##.....</a>
// example Hello how are <a>##you</a> ? I want <a>##join</a>you.

?>
```

Now I want replace all ##.... words with ##.....
example Hello how are ##you ? I want ##join you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'll let others go for regex solutions. I'll propose something that hopefully more readable.*

The following code uses my [Parser class from Paladio](https://gist.github.com/theraot/4b99abf20f3995cc374090487a5c521b) (it's under CC-BY 3.0), it works on UTF-8.

The code is explained in the comments:

```
<?php
    $string = "Hello how are ##you ? I want ##join you.";

    // now I want replace all ##.... words with <a>##.....</a>

    //Create a parser object for the string
    $parser = new Parser($string);

    //Create a variable to hold the result
    $result = '';

    //While we haven't reached the end of the string
    while($parser->CanConsume())
    {
        //Take all the text until the next '##' or the end of the string
        // and add to the result the string taken
        $result .= $parser->ConsumeUntil('##');
        //If we take a '##'
        if ($parser->Consume('##'))
        {
            //Take the text until the next whitespace or new line
            $tag = $parser->ConsumeUntil(array(' ', "\t", "\r", "\n"));
            //Add the new converted text to the result
            $result .= '<a>###'.$tag.'</a>';
        }
    }

    // example Hello how are <a>##you</a> ? I want <a>##join</a>you.
    echo $result;
?>
```

---

Based on the comments, this is a modified version that will allow to detect words marked with any of the given strings (`'##'` and `'**'` in the example):

```
function autolink($ptext, $detc)
{
    // declared whitespace for readability and performance
    $whitespace = array(' ', "\t", "\r", "\n");
    $parser = new Parser($ptext);
    $result = '';
    while($parser->CanConsume())
    {
        $result .= $parser->ConsumeUntil($detc);
        if ($parser->Consume($detc))
        {
            $newtag = $parser->ConsumeUntil($whitespace);
            $result .= '<a href='.$newtag.'>'.$newtag.'</a>';
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
echo autolink("Hello how are ##you ? I want **join you.", array('##', '**'));
```

Outputs:

```
Hello how are <a href=you>you</a> ? I want <a href=join>join</a> you.
```

*Tested on my local server*.

---

*Notes*:

1. The instruction `$parser->Consume($detc)` will return the found string, so you can use it to branch, example:

   $input = $parser->Consume(array('a', 'b'));
   if ($input === 'a')
   {
   // do something
   }
   else if ($input === 'b')
   {
   // do something else
   }
   else /*if ($input === null)*/
   {
   // fallback case
   }
2. The supported things to `Consume` are:

1. Given strings.
2. Arrays of strings.
3. Numbers (amount of characters).
4. Null (will consume a single character).

3. `Parser` uses `mb_*` functions for some of the operations^, and expects `UTF-8`. If you experience problems with encoding you want to call `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` before using `Parser` and convert your string to UTF-8 (I recommend [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for this operation). ^: Some other parts are optimized using byte per byte operations.

Comment: @EthicalRajesh glad of being of help. As mentioned, I'm the author of this library, feel free to make suggestions, and please report any problems. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much I will use it on www.rdtcportal.com [Articles Section]

Comment: Thanks so much I working fine for ##. Is possible that I can detect two strings like ## and ** together without call two times?

Comment: I try with its but failed.

function autolink($ptext,$detc) {

include_once("includes/class/autolink.class.php");

$newword = array_unique(explode(',',$detc));

 foreach ($newword as $key => $oldtag)
 {  $oldtag = trim($oldtag);

$parser = new Parser($ptext);
$result = '';
while($parser->CanConsume()) {
  $result .= $parser->ConsumeUntil($oldtag);
   if ($parser->Consume($oldtag))
   {$newtag = $parser->ConsumeUntil(array(' ', "\t", "\r", "\n"));
   $result .= "<a href='/$newtag/'>$newtag</a>";}}
  
} 

return $result;}

#######################
autolink($mytext,'##,**');

Comment: @EthicalRajesh yes, you can detect two strings in a single call, just pass an array to `Consume` instead of a string. `Consume` will return the string that found. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sir, please please explain note 1 with example like function autolink example. Thanks Last question :)

Comment: My answer already has some code in the notes, so I guess what you want is a use case. Maybe the one at [How to write a recursive regex that matches nested parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20570533/402022) can help you, there I use it to check for "(" or ")". Other than that, tell me what are you tring to do.