# Recursive regex for templating sub loops

Tags: regex, templates, recursion

So I looked at [How to write a recursive regex that matches nested parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569306/how-to-write-a-recursive-regex-that-matches-nested-parentheses) and other solutions for recursive regex matching, but I'm still not getting a proper match on RegexBuddy.

I have a generic handlebars-style template that I want to parse myself, a table with headings:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each columns as col }}<th>{{col}}</th>{{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each rows as row }}
        <tr>
            {{#each row as col }}<td>col</td>{{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And trying to match with

```js
/{{\#each (\w+) as (\w+) }}(.*?|(?R)){{/each}}/s
```

The regex matches the `{{#each columns...` in the `<thead>` just fine, but it seems to ignore the `|(?R)` part and matches `{{#each rows...` only until the *first* `{{/each}}`. I, of course, would like it to match both the inner and outer `#each` expressions. How? This is perhaps much more complex than simple nested parentheses.

(I always feel like I'm a pro at RegEx until I run into things like this. I have been trying for a while to make this work, and regular-expressions.info is just confusing me more.)

---

I'm currently working around this by doing `{{#each_sub...}}...{{/each_sub}}` so my regex won't stop on the first closing tag, but that's obviously a sub-optimal way of doing it. I have several other applications that would benefit from recursive regex but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `[^()]*` in the regex you link to means *not the  leading nor trailing boundary*. Thus, you need something like [`{{#each (\w+) as (\w+) }}(?:(?!{{#each\b[^}]*}}|{{\/each}}).)*(?:(?R)(?:(?!{{#each\b[^}]*}}|{{\/each}}).)*)*+{{\/each}}`](https://regex101.com/r/sT4yB2/1).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew! That matches exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't ignoring the recursion, it's just never reaching it.  Because `.*?` is capable of matching your delimiters (`{{#each...}}` and `{{/each}}`), it matches the first closing delimiter it finds and reports success without ever needing to recurse.

For this technique to work, the branch before the `(?R)` has to match anything that's *not* a delimiter.  Since your delimiters consist of multiple characters, you can't use a negated character class, as they did in the question you linked to.  Instead, you need to use a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
(?:(?!{{[#/]each\b).)*
```

This is the same as `.*`, except before it consumes each character it checks to make sure it's not the beginning of `{{#each` or `{{/each`.  Here it is in context:

```
{{\#each (\w+) as (\w+) }}(?:(?:(?!{{[#/]each\b).)*|(?R))*{{/each}}
```

If the first branch fails, it means you've encountered something that looks like a delimiter.  If it's an *opening* delimiter, the second branch takes over and tries to match the whole pattern recursively.  Otherwise, it pops out of the loop (note the `*` after the group--you were missing that, too) and tries to match a closing delimiter.

While the regex above will work fine on valid input, it's subject to catastrophic backtracking if input is malformed.  To avoid that, you can use an [unrolled loop](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#unrolled_staralt) in place of the alternation (as @Wiktor did in his comment):

```
{{\#each\s+(\w+)\s+as\s+(\w+)\s*}}(?:(?!{{[#/]each\b).)*(?:(?R)(?:(?!{{[#/]each\b).)*)*{{/each}}
```

Here's a slightly more readable version, with possessive quantifiers added to squeeze out even more speed:

```
{{\#each\s+(\w+)\s+as\s+(\w+)\s*}}
(?:(?!{{[#/]each\b).)*+
(?:
  (?R)
  (?:(?!{{[#/]each\b).)*+
)*+
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer, I don't think I would have stumbled upon this easily. It's working in my application. It'll take me a bit to understand how it's working, but your answer is a great resource. Thanks to you and Wiktor!