# How to get everything between brackets but only those, which are not wrapped into brackets themselves

Tags: php, regex

By now i'm using regex: `'/{(.*?)}/'` to get everything inside curly barackets in strings like: `'abc {get me} def {and get me}'` which works fine.

Now i'm looking for a way to exclude brackets, which are surrounded by brackets themselves. The string should be self-explanatory: `'abc {get me {!but not me!}} def {and get {!but not me again!} me} ghi'`.

The following code should illustrate my needs...

```
<?php
$regex  = '/{(.*?)}/';
$string = 'abc {get me {!but not me!}} def {and get {!but not me again!} me} ghi';
preg_match_all( $regex, $string, $matches );
print_r( $matches[1] );
?>
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => get me {!but not me!
    [1] => and get {!but not me again!
)
```

**but should be:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => get me {!but not me!}
    [1] => and get {!but not me again!} me
)
```

Until now i was not able to find a solution via Google and looking forward to get one at SO.

regards

**EDIT:**
[Actually a very similar question was asked and answered on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569306/how-to-write-a-recursive-regex-that-matches-nested-parentheses) But if you are not familiar with regex it's really hard to change from wrapper **(...)** to **{...}**. So you can not simply take the one pattern given by the answer (see link above) and search-replace all '(' & ')' with '{' & '}'. You really have to understand what's going on there.

*But if you understand this pattern enough to customize it you probably would be able to write it on your own...*

Comment: Theoretical informatics says that this is not possible, the problem requires a turing machine, since it is non-regular (needs some form of mode or storage during the search).

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/xY5rR3/3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a recursive regex that matches nested parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569306/how-to-write-a-recursive-regex-that-matches-nested-parentheses)

Comment: Indeed the duplicate matches my needs but as i'm not that good at regex-stuff i was not able to figure out which '(' and ')' change to '{' and '}'.

Comment: I made a little script to generate the pattern automatic while giving left and right limiter. See my answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a **[recursive regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)** with a capturing group that would capture the contents inside the curly braces:

```
{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)}
```

**Explanation**:

- `{` - a literal `{` (in PHP PCRE, you do not need to escape this character)
- `(` - Start of the capturing group 1

  - `(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*` - zero or more sequences (see `(?:...)*`) of 1+ characters other than `{` and `}` (see `[^{}]++`) or the *whole pattern* (`(?R)` is a placeholder for the whole pattern, like `(?0)` subroutine call)
- `)` - end of Group 1
- `}` - closing literal `}`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tC7oI7/1) and the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/ari1NJ):

```
$re = '~{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)}~'; 
$str = "abc {get me {!but not me!}} def {and get {!but not me again!} me} ghi"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here is a script to generate the regex pattern with *variable* right and left delimiters.

```
$delimiter_wrap  = '~';
$delimiter_left  = '{';/* put YOUR left delimiter here.  */
$delimiter_right = '}';/* put YOUR right delimiter here. */

$delimiter_left  = preg_quote( $delimiter_left,  $delimiter_wrap );
$delimiter_right = preg_quote( $delimiter_right, $delimiter_wrap );
$pattern         = $delimiter_wrap . $delimiter_left
                 . '((?:[^' . $delimiter_left . $delimiter_right . ']++|(?R))*)'
                 . $delimiter_right . $delimiter_wrap;

/* Now you can use the generated pattern. */
preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches );
```

**Credits:** Thank you [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) who wrote the answer i accepted...