# RegExp in PHP. Get text between first level parentheses

Tags: php, regex, parentheses, non-greedy

I have two type of strings in one text:

> a(bc)de(fg)h
>
> a(bcd(ef)g)h

I need to get text between first level parentheses. In my example this is:

> bc
>
> fg
>
> bcd(ef)g

I tried to use next regular expression `/\((.+)\)/` with Ungreedy (U) flag:

> bc
>
> fg
>
> bcd(ef

And without it:

> bc)de(fg
>
> bcd(ef)g

Both variants don't do what I need. Maybe someone know how solve my issue?

Comment: why Regex? Simple iteration over the string would work

Comment: are you trying to process each string separately OR they are a part of arbitrary text?

Comment: This strings are a part of one text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569306/how-to-write-a-recursive-regex-that-matches-nested-parentheses) pretty much has the answer, but the implementations are a little ambiguous. You can use the logic in the accepted answer without the `~`s to get this regex:

```
\(((?:\[^\(\)\]++|(?R))*)\)
```

[Tested](https://regex101.com/r/3ad0KJ/1) with this output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use PCRE [***Recursive pattern***](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php#regexp.reference.recursive) to match substrings in nested parentheses:

```
$str = "a(bc)de(fg)h some text a(bcd(ef)g)h ";
preg_match_all("/\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\)/", $str, $m);

print_r($m[1]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bc
    [1] => fg
    [2] => bcd(ef)g
)
```

---

`\( ( (?>[^()]+) | (?R) )* \)`

> First it matches an opening parenthesis. Then it matches any number of
>   substrings which can either be a sequence of non-parentheses, or a
>   recursive match of the pattern itself (i.e. a correctly parenthesized
>   substring). Finally, there is a closing parenthesis.

---

***Technical cautions:***

> If there are more than ***15*** capturing parentheses in a pattern, PCRE has
>   to obtain extra memory to store data during a recursion, which it does
>   by using pcre_malloc, freeing it via pcre_free afterwards. If no
>   memory can be obtained, it saves data for the first 15 capturing
>   parentheses only, as there is no way to give an out-of-memory error
>   from within a recursion.

Comment: How would one match the second level here, ie `ef` (out of curiosity) ? +1 anyway.

Comment: @Jan, `(ef)` become *a recursive match of the pattern itself* (i.e. of the "parent" pattern)

Answer (score -1):

Please can you try that:

```
preg_match("/\((.+)\)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Test this code in http://www.phpliveregex.com/

```
Regex: \((.+)\)
Input: a(bcd(eaerga(er)gaergf)g)h
Output: array(2
   0    =>  (bcd(eaerga(er)gaergf)g)
   1    =>  bcd(eaerga(er)gaergf)g
)
```