# Ignore all chars between marks on regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to ignore all between two marks, but what I get is all inside it.

With the regex `'.*?'` and input `asd'asd'asd 'asd'asd` I get only the matches `'asd'` and `'asd'`.

https://regex101.com/r/hHz48H/1

How can I match the opposite of it?

Comment: You could replace the matches with an empty string, this does not give you the separate parts though..

Comment: Please clarify what do you want to get as an output for your sample

Comment: I have an odataexpression to split, I need to split all 'and' and 'or' operators of string.
But, I cannot split text inside of quotation mark.

Example:

$filter=(Filter eq ' or ' or Filter eq ' and ')

I want only split the single Or operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A regular expression that matches any single character not matched by another regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76816665/a-regular-expression-that-matches-any-single-character-not-matched-by-another-re)

Comment: If you want to avoid filtering for some reason, I guess [`(?<=^(?:[^']*|'[^']*')+)[^']+`](https://regex101.com/r/GMKlGE/1) would work too.

Comment: @InSync That solves the problem. Here the regex: https://regex101.com/r/oJJrcZ/1
Thanks

Comment: your regex is good if you change from match to split: `"foo'asd'bar 'asd'baz" -split "'.*?'"`