# How do I get my Regex to capture pairs of curly braces and stop matching after the pair

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Say we are looking at some text like below

```ts
type vehicle = {
    type: 'car' | 'truck',
    cylinders: number,
    options: string[],
    trim: {
        upholstery: string,
        exteriorColor: string,
        gearbox: string
    }
}

export {
    vehicle
}
```

I want to capture "type vehicle = {.....}" So the match would be

```ts
type vehicle = {
    type: 'car' | 'truck',
    cylinders: number,
    options: string[],
    trim: {
        upholstery: string,
        exteriorColor: string,
        gearbox: string
    }
}
```

I was using this RegEx `/type\s*[a-zA-z0-]+\s*=\s*{[\s\S]*}/g`.

The hope was that it would capture `type name = {` stuff between `}`. Well it does that a bit too well, so it will keep capturing as long something starts with "type name =" and it can find pairs of braces. So the export statement is captured as well.

I also tried it with /u for ungreedy but that fails to capture the last brace of the object.

I believe this section is the problem but I am having a hard time finding a solution
`{[\s\S]*}`

Comment: If you are parsing TS, use a parser. Regex is not a suitable tool for this, especially in JS where we have no [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20569361) nor [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406).

Comment: You can't parse this with regex for the same reason you can't parse [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) with regex.

Comment: You'd need to use a regex engine that does balanced text like Pcre, Perl, C#, etc..

Answer (score -1):

If you always have this exact format in the JSON you could use:

```
^type[\s\S]+?^}
```

which matches from `type` up until a `}` at the start of a line.

See: https://regex101.com/r/vmJs4B/latest

However, I concur with the commentors of your question that, in order to generally solve this question regex is not the suited tool.